# Cannot Find Applications to open File

Tags: android, apk

I have an apk file in the attachment(in Email) in my Droid Razr Maxx HD. It says a message - **"Cannot Find Application(s) to open the File"** .

On the other side this apk is installing flawlessly on other devices. I am unable to figure out the problem.

Kindly reply me if someone else also have faced this problem ever.

Comment: What kind of file is it. What app opens it on other devices? Does the Maxx have *that* app installed?

Comment: It is simple APK file with .APK Extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use mail app, it is security managenemt in android. I think that web client will download this.

Comment: You mean we should try to open it with Browser ?

Comment: year, just try it in browser

Comment: Okay, I will let you know. But why it always works successfully with GMAIL ?